# How to get Jenkins Build Parameters from Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins-job which possibly has more than 100 choices for a parameter(param1) and based on that param2,param3,etc will be changing. I don't want to hard-code the values to individual jobs. Please help me with a configuration which gets the param1 from database and retrieve param2 also from database & also based on param1.

Comment: Why downvote this question? It could be a **duplicated** but is a valid question!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Active Choices plugin - that will give you capability of having dynamically generated choices based on previous choices.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin

Active Choices Plugin uses Groovy. Here you will find an example on how to connect from Groovy to Oracle database:
https://gist.github.com/marcelbirkner/180f1f438ef455642451

Happy coding!